# Running Windows 7 on a Mac Pro

Tags: windows-7, mac, development

My question is simple:
Is running Windows 7 on a Mac Pro as the dominant OS a bad idea?

I'm interested in starting some Mac programing but still want to do Windows-based coding.

I'm tossing up between a MacBook Pro + a desktop or just a Mac Pro.

Also, what development tools are available for Mac?

Comment: Hmm.. Windows based coding as in?

Eclipse works on OS X. So that should cover everything except .Net. :-)

And, you can consider having a Windows as a Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should give a better idea of what you wante to do. I.e. What sort of development do you want to do and what tools do you want to run? Once we know that, we can give you better advice as to what sort of setup is best.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a 'dominant' OS is slightly strange on Mac OS. You will need to install Windows using bootcamp, so technically the dominant operating system will be OS X (although you can allocate most of your storage towards Windows). For development tools on the Mac, see:

- XCode
- TextMate
- Eclipse